# Php Null coalescing operator

Tags: php, php-7.1, null-coalescing-operator

I am trying to understand how the `null coalescing operator` does really work. So, I tested many examples after reading the documentation in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) and some posts on stackoverflow.

However, I can't understand this code:

```
<?php 
$x = false ?? 'stackoverflow';
var_dump($x); // bool(false)
```

since it's equivalent to (from [php.net#null-coalescing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op))

```
isset(false) ? false : 'stackoverflow';
```

and since `isset(false)` generates a `fatal error`.

Could, please, someone explain to me?

Comment: Being 'equivalent to' does not mean the same as.

Comment: from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): "In particular, this operator does not emit a notice if the left-hand side value does not exist, just like isset(). This is especially useful on array keys."

Comment: Like it says, it's syntactic sugar for a common use-case of using a ternary operator in conjunction with `isset`. If that's not what you're doing, this isn't the operator you need. The docs could possibly be worded a little better, in fairness.

Comment: Note that it is named the "*Null* Coalescing Operator", not the "False Coalescing Operator".

Answer (score 2):

Null coalescing operator returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL;

Otherwise it returns its second operand.

In your case first operand is false so it is assigned to the variable. For e.g; if you initialize null to first operand then it will assign second operands value as shown.

```
 $a = null;
 $x = $a ?? 'abc';
 var_dump($x);

Result :
string(3) "abc"
```